# Column limits when Importing excel information into DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, import-from-excel

I'm having problems while importing data from an excel sheet, i've 32 columns but when I fill my DataTable it just bring 19 columns. Is there a limit of columns

The code i have is this:

```
using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
            {
                using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                {
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        con.Open();
                        oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        oda.Fill(dt);
                        con.Close();

                        //lleno el DataGridView.
                        grdExcel.DataSource = dt;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is there something special with those columns? Which columns didn't make it into the DataTable?

Comment: nothing in particular, i've just seen that in properties of the file differs from new files i create from scratch. The original file has mor tabs than the one i create from excel

Comment: wait, more *tabs*? or more *columns*?

Comment: outside the excel itself, when you right click it and go to properties it shows more tabs. I don't know if i'm explaining it well